# Open ports on a website

Tags: robots.txt

Alright. I risk sounding like an absolute newbie but I've got to know this.

A friend and I paid a developer to develop a website for a start-up we had come up with. The idea fell through and the start up never really took off. We've still been paying the developer a small yearly domain renewal fee.

Now recently, I did an nmap intense TCP scan on my domain. I found out that there were 11 ports open. Initially I was a little worried for the security but I then did the same test on 'google.com' and I found 2 open ports - 80 and 443 which made me think that open ports were probably not that big an issue.

But then I cross-referenced the purpose of each open port on my domain. IMAP, POP3, FTP to name a few.

A UDP scan revealed 13 open ports.

I tried to gain access to these ports via telnet and I got in as far as the login page or the opening Dovecot page on cmd but could not progress any further - but I was convinced that a reasonably skilled hacker could easily break in.

Are my worries unfounded?

Comment: Sorry but this is considered off-topic because it is more about server administration rather than webmastering.

Comment: Your not port scanning the website or domain... your domain resolves to an IP address and it is the server that your domain points too that is scanned. You can find out how to close ports under Linux on the Unix Stack such a this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140021/how-to-close-ports-in-linux) and better that you do so using SSH not telnet or if Windows hosting [Super User](https://superuser.com/) If your web hosting is provided by a web hosting company then you should talk to them.